# Trying to use VScode web as a online ide in my project with sandpack-client as a live preview

Tags: vscode-extensions, vscode-webview

I can able access vscode web with extension.js/extension.ts public API's. but I can't able to send updated code to sandpack client. basically I need to send updated code from vscode web to sanpdpack compiler. sandpack client is separate JS file.

tried to expose vscode object outside context but not worked.